# What does it mean for a custom command to have the same file listed in OUTPUT and BYPRODUCTS?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, the [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) accepts arguments for OUTPUT and BYPRODUCTS. I figured these lists would be mutually exclusive, but it seems to be fine if the same file is part of both lists. Does CMake do anything different if the file is in both lists in contrast to having it just in the OUTPUT list?

Comment: BYPRODUCTS: "Specify the files the command is expected to produce but whose modification time may or may not be newer than the dependencies." OUTPUT: "Specify the output files the command is expected to produce." According to that description, OUTPUT seems to be superior of BYPRODUCTS. So listing a file in both lists is effectively the same as listing it in the OUTPUT only.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, that's what I would assume too from the documentation. I would like confirmation that there isn't something that BYPRODUCTS does that OUTPUT doesn't. Some parts of the documentation suggest that BYPRODUCTS may provide additional support for Ninja generators, and it's not clear that it isn't implicitly the same for OUTPUT.

Comment: "Some parts of the documentation suggest that BYPRODUCTS may provide additional support for Ninja generators, and it's not clear that it isn't implicitly the same for OUTPUT." - OUTPUT is **not a replacement** for BYPRODUCTS. If a command *creates* a file, but not always *updates* it, then you should to NOT specify this file in OUTPUT. And most generators correctly work with that setup. But for make Ninja to work, you need to specify that file in BYPRODUCTS. This is what the documentation means. Also, BYPRODUCTS could be used for `add_custom_target`, which doesn't accept OUTPUT at all.

Comment: So, putting this all together: BYPRODUCTS should include any files created by the command but not always updated by the command. OUTPUT should only include files that are always updated. Including files that are always updated in BYPRODUCTS as well as OUTPUT is no different from including them only in OUTPUT. By convention, it is probably best to keep the two lists mutually exclusive. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. OUTPUT normally includes only those files, which are updated by the COMMAND every time it is run. BYPRODUCTS normally includes only files, which are created by the COMMAND, but could be not updated every time the command runs. There is no reason to put the same file into both lists.

Comment: Thanks! Do you want to convert this to an answer so I can accept it?